# Is it possible to dimension a new variable based on array value?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a lot of fields for which I would need to define a new variable.  The list of fields is likely to change, so I'd like to put the listing of fields in a string to populate an array.  From there, I want to loop through the array and dimension the variable.  When I run code similar to below, I get the compile error "Constant expression required."  If something like this isn't possible, is there a better way to achieve a similar result?

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim strFields as String
Dim arrFields() as String

strFields = "Field1|Field2|Field3"

arrFields = split(strFields,"|")

For Each x In arrFields()
    Dim arrFields(x) As String
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: You can't create "dynamic" variable names like that in VBA (if I understand what you're trying to do).  If you want something like that then use a Dictionary object with your names as keys.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Tim.   I will look into using a dictionary object.

Comment: If that doesn't work then you could declare a second string array with the same dimensions as `arrFields` and use that to hold the "values".

Comment: Similar request here (applies to properties of a class object, but the principle is the same), with example of using Dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22874920/vba-sub-insert-text-string-into-class-object-reference/22881385#22881385

Comment: Thanks guys - I was finally able to get my code to work with a dictionary object. Really appreciate the help.